# Mixing abstract class inheritance with instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Ok, I know that -mainly due to complexity- virtual template methods aren't allowed.

However, considering this:

```
// something.h

class absClass
{
public:
    // ...
    // instead of templating the absClass fun method, define the different
    // overloads that are going to be used:
    virtual void fun(classA a) = 0;
    virtual void fun(classB b) = 0;
};

class impClass : public absClass
{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    void fun(T t)  
    { /* whatever */ }

    // declaration
    void fun(classA a);
    void fun(classB b);
};
```

And then we establish specific instantiation of the method in impClass?

```
// something.cpp
#include "something.h"

// instantiation
void impClass::fun<classA>(classA t);
void impClass::fun<classB>(classB t);
```

Isn't that supposed to work? I am getting errors (whether if they are instantiated in the .h or the .cpp).

Comment: You need to put `template<>` before those declarations.

Comment: template<> is for specialization, while I want to instantiate them. Or am I deadly wrong?

Comment: Oops sorry in that case you need just `template` without the `<>` (the compiler will also deduce the types so `<classA>` etc. is superfluous).

Comment: Well, the reality is more complex because `fun` is a template with two typenames and only one is specified in the signature (so in my case it requires the <>). You're hinting in the right direction though! Even though it seems that it's not instantiating properly...

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you if your actual code is different to what you posted above.

Comment: I know... but the original code is mastodontic... I basically wanted to know if the concept of instantiation of methods is combinable with abstract classes in that way... so I can keep trying to solve this :)

Comment: What do you mean by not instantiating properly btw, have you tried seeing if the symbols are present in the object file?

Comment: I just meant that the linker does complain about undefined references to the functions declared, even though they are supposed to be instantiated from the template in the .cpp. Thanks, I'll inspect the object file to see what does it generate!

Comment: if there are 2 template arguments, then you have to provide both of them to make a successful explicit instantiation; but, afterall, the explicit instantiation is not related to your abstract class...they are different functions even the signatures are the same. The instantiations ARE NOT implementing pure virtual functions.

Comment: I provide both arguments. The thing is that the two functions generated by the template instantiation have to have the same signature that is to be expected (and it is declared in the .h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ---- something.h
class absClass
{
public:
    // ...
    // instead of templating the absClass fun method, define the different
    // overloads that are going to be used:
    virtual void fun(classA a) = 0;
    virtual void fun(classB b) = 0;
};

class impClass : public absClass
{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    void fun(T t)  
    { 
        /* whatever */ #1
    }

    // declaration
    void fun(classA a)
    {
        // #2 -- the implementation of base class pure virtual function
        // Note: you must define this function, otherwise there is linker error
    }
    void fun(classB b)
    {
    }
};

//  ---- something.cpp
#include "something.h"

// instantiation
template void impClass::fun<classA>(classA t); // add missing "template"
template void impClass::fun<classB>(classB t); // add missing "template"

//  ---- main.cpp
impClass o;
classA a;
o.fun<classA>(a); // calls #1
o.fun(a); // calls #2
```

Since you are writing `void impClass::fun<classA>(classA t);` then you are doing specialization, so you need to add `template<>` before it.

But this is not the function body of your implementation of virtual function, they are other things...check the 2 different calls I provided.

---

Edit#1, based comment:

Well there's still point for specialization, if you want to achieve something special for specific class, right?

By the way what is the point of instantiation then? Are you trying to export the class template?

---

Edit#2, based comment:

Is that what you want?

```
class impClass : public absClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void so_fun(T t)  
    { 
        /* whatever */
        /* define the common behavior here */
    }
    void fun(classA a)
    {
        so_fun(a);
    }
    void fun(classB b)
    {
        so_fun(b);
    }
};
```

or:

```
template <typename T>
void so_fun(T t)  
{ 
    /* whatever */
    /* define the common behavior here */
}

class impClass : public absClass
{
public:
    void fun(classA a)
    {
        so_fun(a);
    }
    void fun(classB b)
    {
        so_fun(b);
    }
};
```

Comment: What would be the point of templates if I have to specialize each and every function signature? That's why I mean instantiation instead of specialization...

Comment: By instantiating the function template I want to define methods that do the same over different arguments, without having to copy paste code. And that to be invisible to the outside classes that call the methods based on the "interface" defined by the abstract class.

Comment: Ok, the problem is, these instantiation does not implement the interfaces defined by the abstract class. Did you notice the different function calls in my example? `o.fun(a)` and `o.fun<classA>(a)` jump into different functions. If you do not define `fun(classA a)` then you would get a linker error.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way around it? While trying to avoid repeating code? To tell the compiler that the instantiation of the template is going to implement the abstract class method?

Comment: I mean, try to imagine that the function template is gigantic and there's multiple instantiations of it. It's just not worth specializing all of them when they all do the same (or avoid using templates and instead use function overloading). Oh my, mixing OOP and templating is quite problematic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58468/discussion-between-huff-and-marson-mao).

Comment: You still have to implement the interfaces, but now you just delegate the real stuff to `super_fun`, and it does all the same procedure.